# How can I PHP include based on dropdown choice?

Tags: php, html

I'm want to show php include based on the drop down menu choice.
But the trick is that I want to show the include before submitting the page.

```
<?php include 'page.php'; ?>

<select name="s1"style="width: 70px;" >
          <optgroup label="My Input">
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          <option value="one kind</option>
          <option value="second kind</option>
</select>
```

How can I show my page based on option selected before page is submited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```